# Transfer files between bootcamp partitions

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, file-transfer

I am using Snow Leopard and Windows 7 with bootcamp. I would like to be able to save some files to my OSX partition from Windows. I would also like to have files (say, photos, source code, etc) that I can manage with both partitions. Is it possible to get the two partitions to "play nice"?

Comment: macdrive on windows, and ntfs-3G for Mac os x

Comment: it seems paragon has a [bundle](http://www.cleverbridge.com/80/uurl-duw82qa7bd) which is nearly 2x cheaper than macdrive

Comment: https://mac-torrent-download.net/?s=Paragon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices:

NTFS in Mac OS X:

- [Paragon NTFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) (US$19.95)
- [Tuxera NTFS for Mac](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) (€25)
- [NTFS-3G](http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/NTFS-3G%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/2010.10.2/ntfs-3g-2010.10.2-macosx.dmg/download) (free)

HFS+ in Windows:

- [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/) (US$49.99)
- [Paragon HFS for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) (US$19.95)

There is a bundle promotion for Paragon NTFS and Paragon HFS for Windows, available [here](http://www.cleverbridge.com/80/uurl-duw82qa7bd).