# my passport for Mac on a PC

Tags: macos, windows, photos, sharing

I have photos on My Pass0port for Mac and attempted without success to download other photos using my Acer which uses Windows 10

Comment: What errors did you get? Could you see anything on the drive or even that there was a drive?

Answer (score 1):

By default the Mac formats external drives with HFS+ format. You'd need to load software on your PC to read that filesystem or return the drive to the Mac to change around the settings.

Search here for things in [filesystem](/questions/tagged/filesystem) and with HFS and [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) for more information.

- [Transfer files between bootcamp partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15878/)
- [Why I can not see mac partition under windows installed with bootcamp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167874/)

Comment: I want so bad to edit the hyperlinks to plain URLs. :)

Comment: @user3439894 let me know if you figure a way to circumvent the custom rendering of site plain url :)